# Ubuntu - sudo with ACL

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, acl, sudo

I am sorry if this is something obvious but I am new to Linux.
I was trying to set a git bare directory and for this I installed ACL on Ubuntu. Then I ran the following commands:

```
adduser git
mkdir /repositories
chmod 700 /repositories
setfacl -m defaut:user::rwx /repositories
sudo chown git:git /repositories
```

Everything was fine until I rebooted the machine. Now I am unable to execute sudo anymore. Everytime I do it as myself I get following message:

```
[[sudo]] password for Andre:
Sorry, try again
```

The password I enter is the same I always used, and I don't have any problem to SSH with these account credentials.
Does anyone knows what happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the issue was with setfacl. I should have used 'repositories' instead of '/repositories'. In that way I set acl across the root. I ended up reinstalling Linux.